# ProcessBuilder error when open second word file

Tags: java, cmd, ms-word, runtime.exec, processbuilder

I have a problem on this code:

```
      try {
            log.info("init");
            ProcessBuilder pb;
            Process p;
            pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/C", path+"\\test.docx");

            p = pb.start();
            p.waitFor();

            log.info("final");
        }
```

It works, but when i have another open word file in my machine the process doesn't **wait**.

The word file *test.docx* opens, but prints **"final"** **before** i closed it.

if i don't have another open word file in machine it prints **"final"** **after** i closed word *teste.docx* (As it's supposed to be).

I try to fixed like that:

```
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start /wait "+path+"test.docx");
```

or

```
pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/C","start" ,"/B","/belownormal","/WAIT", path+"\\test.docx").redirectErrorStream(true);
```

but nothing works, any ideas?

Comment: what does `waitFor()` return? put something like `int i = p.waitFor();`...

Comment: When i open another word file the process is the same as the first (**winword.exe**)! This causes the problem. Any ideas?

Comment: @AlexandroSifuentesDíaz `int i = p.waitFor();` always return 0.

Comment: See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process.